# How to move react-material-ui-carousel indicators

Tags: reactjs, typescript, indicator, react-material-ui-carousel

I have a carousel and dots indicators. I would like to move the indicators from the bottom to the circle shown below in the picture.
I tried to set negative margin-top, but then the indicators get hidden. How can I achieve this?
[image]

```
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import Item from "./CarouselItems/Item";
import FirstImage from "../../assets/images/first.jpg";
import LastImage from "../../assets/images/lastslide.jpg";

const CarouselComponent: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <MyCarousel
      autoPlay={false}
      swipe={true}
      indicators={true}
      indicatorContainerProps={{
        style: {
          marginTop: "-50px"
        },
      }}
    >
      <Item />
      <Item />
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default MyCarousel;
```

Comment: Could you share a simple sample of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: @MajidM. I have just added it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following styles to `indicatorContainerProps`:

```
  indicatorContainerProps={{
    style: {
      zIndex: 1,
      marginTop: "-10px",
      position: "relative"
    }
  }}
```

[image: Edit cranky-zhukovsky-gur8mc]

Answer (score 1):

another approach that you can use :

```
indicatorContainerProps={{
        className: 'custom-indicator-container',
      }}
```

and you can use css to edit it this way :

```
.custom-indicator-container {
  bottom: 10px;
}
```