# How to move react-material-ui-carousel indicators avobe carousel

Tags: material-ui

i alreaady read [How to move react-material-ui-carousel indicators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048272/how-to-move-react-material-ui-carousel-indicators) this link

so i tried marginTop: -200px

but reslut is no good for me

[result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqWiy.png)

see this image, that yellow line is i expected, but if i add 'marginTop'

background height together small..

how can i fix it?

below i add all code link in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-babycat-tx0j2o?file=/src/App.js

```
<Carousel
      IndicatorIcon={<Home />} // Previous Example
      indicatorIconButtonProps={{
        style: {
          padding: '10px', // 1
          color: 'blue', // 3
        },
      }}
      activeIndicatorIconButtonProps={{
        style: {},
      }}
      indicatorContainerProps={{
        style: {
          textAlign: 'center',
          zIndex: 1,
          marginTop: '-200px',
          position: 'relative',
        },
      }}
    >
```

Comment: How would you like the final image to look?  Just move the carousel indicators down into the white area?